# How to do text search with score from mongodb in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In mongodb I can do this :

```
db.getCollection('keywords').find(
   { $text: { $search: "I have headache" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

result

```
{
    "_id" : "ux2dpeYKQCQRgdbzB",
    "keyword" : "Headache",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-10T01:45:07.670Z"),
    "createdBy" : "a5oNybXwHKB8DkxdB",
    "score" : 1.33333333333333
}
```

and I want do that in meteor :

```
Keywords.find(
                { $text: { $search: keyword } },
                { score: { $meta: "textScore" }, sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
            ).fetch()
```

but it get error :

```
MongoError: must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys
```

I tried like this without sort

```
Keywords.find(
                { $text: { $search: keyword } },
                { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
            ).fetch()
```

but I dont get score field in this document :

```
{
    "_id" : "ux2dpeYKQCQRgdbzB",
    "keyword" : "Headache",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-10T01:45:07.670Z"),
    "createdBy" : "a5oNybXwHKB8DkxdB"
}
```

how to solve this text search in meteor and sort by score?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's weird! I replicated your code below albeit changing it by adding an index:

```
// server/index.js
const Keywords = new Mongo.Collection('keywords');
Keywords.rawCollection().createIndex({ keyword: 'text' });
const simpleQuery = Keywords.find(
  { $text: { $search: 'Headache' } },
  { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } },
).fetch();
console.log(simpleQuery);
```

```
// MongoDB
{
    "_id" : "ux2dpeYKQCQRgdbzB",
    "keyword" : "Headache",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-10T01:45:07.670Z"),
    "createdBy" : "a5oNybXwHKB8DkxdB"
}
```

And it works nicely!